# Http responde failure blob (file xlsx)

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

I want to download file in Angular (xlsx). I use ExcelJS.

The problem that in Swagger the request got 200 and download file correctly but when call on Angular it failed....

The file is create in server nodejs Ts.Ed like :

```
@Get("/")
  @ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
  @Header({
    "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=export.xlsx"
  })
  @Status(200)
  async get(): Promise<Excel.Buffer> {
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Countries List');

    worksheet.addTable({
      name: 'MyTable',
      ref: 'A1',
      headerRow: true,
      totalsRow: true,
      style: {
        theme: 'TableStyleDark3',
        showRowStripes: true,
      },
      columns: [
        {name: 'Date', totalsRowLabel: 'Totals:', filterButton: true},
        {name: 'Amount', totalsRowFunction: 'sum', filterButton: false},
      ],
      rows: [
        [new Date('2019-07-20'), 70.10],
        [new Date('2019-07-21'), 70.60],
        [new Date('2019-07-22'), 70.10],
      ],
    });

    return await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
    
    // return "hello";
  }
```

And the front in angular is :

```
export class ExportsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  generateXLSX(): Observable<any> {
    const httpHeaders = { responseType: 'blob'};
    return this.http.get('/exports', {
      headers: httpHeaders
    });
  }
}
```

and :

```
async generatePdf(item: string) {
    lastValueFrom(await this.exportsService.generateXLSX())
      .then((data: any) => {
        let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
        fs.saveAs(blob, 'Export_' + item + '.xlsx');
      })
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // throw e && e.error && e.error.Message;
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          console.log('Status', err.status);
        } else {
          console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
          console.log('Status', err.status);
        }
      });
  }
```

But I got error failure response but have status code to 200..

```
[ErrorHandlerInterceptor] Request error 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/exports", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/api/exports", error: {…} }
```

Thanks for help